# How to handle global state with clean up in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app which has some global state (including several `SoundPool`s, which take a while to load) and I'm looking to find the best way of managing this. So far I can see two options, neither of which are perfect:

1. Store the state in my main `Activity` - this hooks into the `Activity` lifecycle nicely (with opportunity to cleanup), and over screen rotations I can use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance` to retain the state, however when navigating between activities this state will be completely lost and have to be re-loaded, which will be unacceptably slow
2. Store the state in a global singleton or an `Application` subclass - this allows the state to persist over navigation between activities, but because Application doesn't have an `onDestroy` event there is no opportunity to release the `SoundPool`s

Any suggestions on a better way to do this? Or should I not worry about releasing the SoundPools when the app is stopped/killed?

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 2):

Both are not just imperfect, but in fact pretty bad architectures.

The Singleton pattern is more and more criticized in general, and for Android it is even worse since you have no guarantee that your Application object will persist (the system will kill it when resources are low, and that's not a bug but the correct behavior).

onRetainNonConfigurationInstance  is deprecated since API level 13 and is described by the Android team itself as a 'dirty hack'; that's not what you want to use either.

You can solve your Soundpool persistence problem by hosting it in a service independent from your activities. Just be sure to kill the service once nothing needs to be played anymore.

Comment: I'm happy that Android could decide to kill the whole app at any point, but that should usually mean the user if off doing something else. 

I think the configuration methods are merely deprecated because Google would like you to use the fragment equivalents. They also recommend you don't handle configuration changes yourself (presumably since it is easy to cause memory leaks).

My next question would be: given an app can have various activities being created and destroyed as the user navigates between them, how can I determine when to kill the service?

Comment: For example, if I setup the service to be destroyed when the last activity unbinds, won't that stop when the user navigates between activities?

Comment: two things about onRetainNonConfigurationInstance : it is deprecated, meaning that it can be kicked from the sdk at any point in the future. Do you really want to go on with solution and have to rethink your architecture in x months ? the apparition of setRetainInstance is only half of why it was removed, the memory leak problem is not just a the presumably state, it is a real issue of this anti-pattern.

Comment: for a mediaplaying service, I ended up creating it at app start, and destroying it if there is nothing left to play & the user is out of my app. Your requirements may vary but I think you will probably end up with something really similar. A service is really what you want here, they have been designed specifically to answer to this kind of requirements.

Comment: How about each activity register/deregister with the Application (via onResume and onPause), then having the service run a timer to determine if no activities have run for a given amount of time? This all sounds very overly complicated though!

Comment: No need to use the Application class to do this (and again, it is more an anti-pattern than anything else, and creates unnecessary complication). Start the service in the onCreate of one activity (either the start activity, or later if it makes no sense to keep the service alive whereas you app make very limited use of it). Then, at a first implementation, killing it if the user is out of the app and nothing is playing makes sense. A second step would be indeed to add a timer.

Comment: I can see how that would work if there is only one activity, but not if there are multiple?

Comment: I should maybe add that the sounds in my app only play for a few seconds, its not a media player. There's no explicit UI action to finish

Comment: Looking through the Google documentation, that suggests that activity lifecycles deliberately overlap, so no timer needed. I'll post back here if it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isn't a complete answer but I'll follow up with a more specific question.

But in principle, having a local `Service` does work as follows:

- Have a local "bound" service holding the state
- Have various activities, each binding and unbinding to the service, for example:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalStateService.class);
    bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (stateService != null) {
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
        stateService = null;
    }
}
```

Since the activity lifecycle deliberately overlaps, the service will exist until the user exits the app (or simply leaves it and goes off to do something else). At this point, `onUnbind` and then `onDestroy` is called on the service.

Great, we're nearly there. However, the service does not survive a configuration restart (e.g. a screen rotation), so I'll post that as a separate question...